# Expresión para determinar que la variable edad está dentro del rango 0 y 25

Tags: c++

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]hice el algoritmo pero cuando coloco números negativos me imprime en pantalla las dos frases,es decir el rango esta entre 0 y 25 y coloco -1 y me da en pantalla "su edad es -1 la edad no es correcta" que debo hacer?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>

using namespace std;

main()
{
    int edad;
    cout<<"escribir edad "; cin>>edad;

    if (edad>0<=25)
    {
        cout<<"su edad es " <<edad;
    }
    else(edad<0>25);
    {
        cout<<"la edad no es correcta";// cuando escribo numeros negativos como -1 en adelante me imprime las dos frases
    }
    getch();
}
```

Comment: Deberías editar tu pregunta y no hacerla dependiente de la imagen. Si el link deja de funcionar en un momento dado tu pregunta no le será útil a nadie.

Comment: "*cuando coloco números negativos me imprime en pantalla las dos frases*" me parece muy raro, porque el programa ni siquiera compila.

Answer (score 5):

Si tu escribes por ejemplo:

```
int edad=30;
int res = 0<edad;
printf("%d",res);
```

La salida será `1`. Una comparación devolverá **siempre** `1` en caso afirmativo o `0` en caso negativo.

Esto quiere decir que si yo hago:

```
int edad=30;
int res = 0<edad<=25;
printf("%d",res);
```

En el caso de funcionar haría `(0<edad)<=25`, que devuelve lo siguiente:

```
0<edad = 0<30 = 1
1<=25 = 1
```

Y desde luego no es el resultado que esperas, ya que el resultado final, en este caso, debería ser `0` o `falso`

Lo que tienes que hacer es hacer dos comparaciones individuales y, dado que tienen que cumplirse las dos a la vez, unirlas con un operador AND:

```
if(0<edad && edad<=25)
```

Otro problema de tu código se encuentra aquí:

```
if( edad>0<=25) 
  // ...
else ( edad<0>25); { // <<--- AQUI
}
```

En C++ los condicionales tienen la siguiente forma:

```
if( /* condicion */ )
  /* codigo a ejecutar si se cumple la condicion */
else
  /* codigo a ejecutar en caso contrario */
```

Y fíjate que en el `else` no se añaden condiciones. La única forma de añadir condiciones es concatenando ifs:

```
if( /* condicion1 */ )
  /* codigo a ejecutar si se cumple condicion1 */
else if ( /* condicion2 */ )
  /* codigo a ejecutar si no se cumple condicion1 y sí se cumple condicion2 */
else if ( /* condicion3 */ )
  /* codigo a ejecutar si no se cumple condicion1 ni condicion2 y sí se cumple condicion3 */
```

Por otro lado, debes tener en cuenta que si no se cumple la condición del `if`, se ejecutará el código que haya en el `else`. Este detalle implica que no hace falta hacer comparaciones complementarias. Es decir, este código:

```
if( a<=5 )
  printf("'a' es menor o igual a 5\n");
else if( a > 5 )
  printf("'a' es mayor que 5\n");
```

Es equivalente a este otro:

```
if( a<=5 )
  printf("'a' es menor o igual a 5\n");
else
  printf("'a' es mayor que 5\n");
```

Siendo además este segundo ejemplo más sencillo de entender y de mantener.

Las concatenaciones de varios ifs se producen cuando hay más de dos caminos posibles. Por ejemplo:

```
if( 10 > edad )
  // edad<10
else if( 18 > edad )
  // 10<=edad<18
else if( 40 >= edad )
  // 18<=edad<40
else if( 60 < edad && 80 > edad )
  // 60<edad<80
else
  // 40<=edad<=60 o 80<=edad
```

Y, para rematar, cuidado con el uso del punto y coma. Si lo pones después de un `if`, un `for` o un `while` el resultado no te va a gustar:

```
int var = 0;
for( int i=0;i<10;i++); {
  var++;
}
std::cout << var;
```

¿Qué va a imprimir el código anterior? Lo normal sería que sacase un 10 por pantalla... pero si te fijas verás que justo detrás del `for` hay un punto y coma... en consecuencia el código `var++` no pertenece al bucle y únicamente se ejecutará una vez (aunque esté encerrado entre llaves). El programa imprimirá entonces `1`.

Answer (score 2):

La instrucción `edad<0>25` no funciona como crees, no significa "*edad menor que cero y mayor que veinticinco*". Primero se evalúa `edad<0` y después se usa el resultado de esa expresión para comprobar si es mayor que veinticinco: `el-resultado-de-antes>25`.

- Si `edad` es menor que cero, el resultado será `true` así que comprobarás: `true>25`, que **siempre será falso** porque `true` se considerará `1` ergo: es falso que uno sea mayor que veinticinco.
- Si `edad` es mayor que cero, el resultado será `false` así que comprobarás: `false>25`, que **siempre será falso** porque `false` se considerará `0` ergo: es falso que cero es mayor que veinticinco.

Pero todo eso da igual porque tienes un `;` después del `else`:

```
else(edad<0>25); // <--------------------------------
{
    cout<<"la edad no es correcta";// cuando escribo numeros negativos como -1 en adelante me imprime las dos frases
}
```

Eso hace que la instrucción del `else` sea vacía y el bloque entre llaves se ejecuta **siempre**... o así sucedería si esto siquiera compilase, porque los `else` no contienen instrucción de comparación, para eso debería ser un `else if (comparación)`.

Por otro lado, tienes el mismo problema con la instrucción `edad>0<=25`, primero se evalúa `edad>0` y se usa el resultado para comprobar si es menor o igual a veinticino: `el-resultado-de-antes<=25`.

- Si `edad` es menor que cero, el resultado será `false` así que comprobarás: `false<=25`, que **siempre será verdadero** porque `false` se considerará `0` ergo: es verdadero que cero es menor o igual que veinticinco.
- Si `edad` es mayor que cero, el resultado será `true` así que comprobarás: `true<=25`, que **siempre será verdadero** porque `true` se considerará `1` ergo: es verdadero que uno es menor o igual que veinticinco.

---

Tus comparaciones deben ser:

```
if (edad > 0 && edad <=25)
{
    ...
}
else
{
    ...
}
```